# Get FancyHDR and geometry to work nicely

Tags: fancyhdr, geometry

In the MWE, geometry is set to leave a top margin of 1cm on the top and on the back of the page. Yet, with FancyHDR on the top of that, occupy some parts of this margin and I have to manually tweak the margins in geometry to get an descent margin.

Is there some correction I could do to have this sorted out automatically ?
NB: I compile with xelatex.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec} % 

\usepackage[hidelinks,xetex]{hyperref}

\usepackage[top=1cm,bottom=1cm,left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,asymmetric]{geometry}
\geometry{bindingoffset=2.1cm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{style}{
    \fancyhf{}                          
    \fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark} %\slshape 
    \fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark} %\slshape
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\hyperlink{toc}{\thepage}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}  
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}}
\pagestyle{style}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}

\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It actually is very easy, and I should have read the manual for `geometry` before asking this question. But now it is asked, all there is to do is to add `includeheadfoot` in the options of the geometry package and problem solved.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec} % 

\usepackage[hidelinks,bookmarksnumbered,pagebackref,xetex]{hyperref}

\usepackage[top=0cm,bottom=0cm,left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,includeheadfoot,asymmetric]{geometry}
\geometry{bindingoffset=2.1cm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{style}{
    \fancyhf{}                          
    \fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark} %\slshape 
    \fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark} %\slshape
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\hyperlink{toc}{\thepage}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}  
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}}
\pagestyle{style}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}

\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you suggest how to troubleshoot `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package geometry.` ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to fit your header and footer inside a narrow space; so you need to reduce `headsep` and `footskip`. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}

\usepackage[
  top=1cm,
  bottom=1cm,
  left=0.5cm,
  right=0.5cm,
  headsep=3pt,
  footskip=20pt,
  asymmetric,
  bindingoffset=2.1cm
]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[hidelinks,xetex]{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{style}{%
    \fancyhf{}                          
    \fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark} %\slshape 
    \fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark} %\slshape
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\hyperlink{toc}{\thepage}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}  
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}}
\pagestyle{style}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}

\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

Are you sure you want to use those specifications?

Comment: Thanks, but this only moves the problem from having to tweak top and bottom margins to headsep and footskip. Is there a way it can automatically determine the size of the headings and footers, so if I type top and bottom to 0, the headings and footer touch the edges of the page.

Comment: @HcN No, there isn't.